# Send boolean data in postman form-data

Tags: php, postman

I have tried to send boolean data type using postman form-data, but in php it read as string.
I have tried to convert it using manual casting (bool) and boolVal(), but the result always true whenever I send false or true value in the postman.

Is there any solution with this problem? I can't use it in if statement cause it always return true whenever I tried to cast it to bool.

[image]

```
if ($request->isDiscount) {
   $price = $request->price * 10/100;
}
```

the above code will always get executed whenever the value of isDiscounted is true or false

have tried below too

```
if ($request->isDiscount == true) {
   $price = $request->price * 10/100;
}
```

or

```
if ((bool)$request->isDiscount == true) {
   $price = $request->price * 10/100;
}
```

or

```
 if (boolVal($request->isDiscount) == true) {
       $price = $request->price * 10/100;
 }
```

but the code always get executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are no data-types within the form-data this is pretty normal.
The text `true` is a non-empty string and therefore interpreted as boolean `true` within PHP. The same for the text `false` which is also a non-empty string and therefore interpreted as boolean `true`.

It is up to your code to interpret submitted data as integer/text/boolean/whatever. In this case I would submit the text `1` for `true` and `0` for `false` and on the server's side convert it to integer which you can use for your `if` as integer `0` is interpreted as boolean `false` and all other integers as boolean `true`.

Keep in mind to sanitize all the data submitted to avoid SQL-injections and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with postman, but if it's sending via GET maybe try

```
if ($_GET['isDiscount']) {
       $price = $_GET['isDiscount'] * 10/100;
 }
```

OR

```
$price = $_GET['isDiscount'] ? $_GET['isDiscount']*10/100 : false;
```

Also I sanitize _GET with this function from my library

```
function num ($input){ 
  if(strlen($input) > 24){ $input=0; }
  if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $input)){ $input=0; } 
  return $input;
 }
```

Using function is fun & easy...

```
$discount = num($_GET['isDiscount']) ?: false;
```

For those wondering why I check a numbers length with strlen... years ago a player in my game discovered if he entered in a big enough number, he would give him a butt load of free war units.. you could remove that part or change length.

Let me know if this helps you, i'll check back in 10 mins.

Comment: question edited

Answer (score 0):

PHP reads all form data as strings.

There's 2 approaches you can take (plus more, but I'll explain 2 common ones):

1. Pass data as JSON
2. Use PHP's filter_var function

#### Pass data as JSON

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input

Sending the data as a JSON string and then decode it in PHP. An easy way I've found to do this is like so:

All data will be decoding into the relevant types.

#### Use PHP's filter_var function

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

This allows you to use built-in PHP functions to convert from a string, the the selected type (using the $filter argument).

An example using filter_var to return a bool value:

The drawbacks of using filter_var is that you are limited to interpreting a string which means you need to ensure that data being posted is in the correct format

Comment: Another simple approach is to compare the value as a string and then "type" it yourself

Comment: 1) that solution won't allow to send files with other parameters which include boolean... So is it a server issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that I tried and it was useful

Explanation of the problem:
I wanted to pass the value (Boolean) into a data form, but the response was that dataform did not know the value sent inside the dataform (false).

Solve the problem :
I created a variable called (false) whose value was (false). After that, I passed the variable into the data form, which worked for me.

I hope I have helped you with this solution